# cakephp - how to group results in a different way?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

when using cakephp Model->find() method, I want to group results in a different way.

my schema is :

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deviceid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sessionid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip` text NOT NULL,
  `image_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'invalid_image',
  `filename` text NOT NULL,
  `analysis_basic` text COMMENT 'output from the image script',
  `analysis_admin` text,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sessionid` (`sessionid`)
```

in cakephp i want to get some thing like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Picture] => Array
        (
            [sessionid] => somevalue
        )
        [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 32
            [deviceid] => 5124125
            [userid] => 4541221
            ...and all other fileds
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 35
            [deviceid] => 5124125
            [userid] => 4541221
            ...and all other fileds
        )        
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [Picture] => Array
        (
            [sessionid] => someothervalue
        )
        [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38
            [deviceid] => 5124454
            [userid] => 34241
            ...and all other fileds
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 35
            [deviceid] => 5124454
            [userid] => 34241
            ...and all other fileds
        )
```

is that possible with cakephp? Or is there a better way to achieve something similar to above? If i could obtain results like that, i know all records within [0] element is have same sessionid.. that's why.

Comment: I don't remember cake having a direct function that does what you want, are you open to `foreach` solution?

Comment: @SiGanteng yes, if we don't have another solution. Or do you know plain mysql query that generate result set - could be converted easily to some thing similar.

Comment: No... `group by` in mysql isn't about grouping different results into arrays, so ya.

Comment: so please provide a foreach solution as an answer.

Comment: I just did ;s, note that I might be off, as I don't have your complete code / data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$pictures = $this->Picture->find('all');
$grpPicts = array();

foreach($pictures as $p) {
   $sessid = $p['sessionid'];
   $grpPicts[$sessid]['Picture']['sessionid'] = $sessid;
   $grpPicts[$sessid][] = $p;
}

var_dump(array_values($grpPicts));
```

I know that this isn't the most elegant solution, but it should be close to what you are looking for.

Comment: ok, this may be slow. but it is doing what i want for now. thanks

Comment: for a tiny bit of performance gain, you could use `array_merge($grpPicts, array())`, although I think it's miniscule :s